# Can't run MySql Script because of error on MySql Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I downloaded the MySql Workbench, and then I tried running a few scripts. However, whenever I tried to run a script, I would get an error that said this:

Error During "Run SQL Script"
Error calling Python module function SQLIDEUtils.runSQLScript

No matter what SQL Script I run, I always get this error. Does anybody know how to solve this issue or know what's causing the issue? Please answer!

Here's a picture of the error I receive:

[image: The error I get whenever I try to run a SQL Script.]

Comment: What's the version of your MySql Workbench?

Comment: I'm using version 8.0.21.0 of MySql Workbench.